# Código Selenium/WebDriver para de executar após ler planilha com Apache Poi

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

O meu código de teste usando Selenium/WebDriver deixa de ser executado após ler dados do Apache Poi.

Alguém sabe me dizer o por quê?

```
//poi
WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.name("simcard"));

try {

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\paulo.xls")); 
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    for (int i=1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
        String simcard = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        searchbox.sendKeys(simcard);                
        searchbox.submit();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    workbook.close();
    file.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    fnfe.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

O próximo passo:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/center/table/tbody/tr[19]/td/a[1]/img")).click();
```

Comment: Olá Paulo! O que é "Data Driven" no seu código? Você quer mesmo pesquisar cada linha da planilha e aguardar 10 segundos entre cada pesquisa? O componente `searchbox` deve receber tanto o texto a ser pesquisado como também o `submit`? Não teria um botão?

Comment: Luiz, sou novato em programação, Eu copiei este código e tentei adaptar no meu...Eu quero na verdade que ele abra a planilha, pegue um valor la e coloque no input, não precisa aguardar 10 segundos e nem fazer uma varredura na planilha...Pode reconstruir este trecho de código para mim, por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baseado no meu entendimento sobre o que você quer fazer e algumas suposições, este seria o código que cumpre o objetivo:

```
//referência ao campo de busca
WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.name("simcard"));

try {

    //carrega arquivo com planilha
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\paulo.xls")); 
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

    //recupera primeira planilha (aba)
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    //pega o valor da primeira célula (A1)
    String simcard = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

    //fecha planilha e arquivo (não precisa fechar os dois)
    workbook.close();

    //envia o valor da célula para o campo
    searchbox.sendKeys(simcard);

    //envia o formulário (precisa ser um form normal, se a tela usar JavaScript pode não funcionar)
    searchbox.submit();

    //aguarda 10 segundos (esperar carregar os dados, talvez)
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//próximo passo aqui
```

Observações:

- Não é necessário fechar ambos `workbook` e arquivo. Ao fechar o primeiro, o segundo é fechado automaticamente.
- Você não precisa de um laço para pegar o valor. E a primeira linha começa com `0` e não com `1`.
- Você pode fechar a planilha logo depois de ler o valor.
- Se ainda não funcionar, verifique o console ou log para ver se está ocorrendo alguma exceção. Neste caso, edite sua pergunta e acrescente a pilha de erro.
- Se o programa travar pode ser algum problema do WebDriver com seu navegador. Neste caso, atualize a versão do Selenium/WebDriver, tente outro navegador, verifique se não há um JavaScript executando algo na página que pode causar o travamento.

Comment: Luiz, com o código anterior ele preenchia os dados mas não passava para o proximo passo, mas com este código que você passou Ele não preenche o campo simcard, com o valor da planilha, e não executa o proximo passo também.

Comment: Provavelmente o código não está encontrando o valor na planilha. Verifique se o valor a ser pesquisado está na célula A1 da planilha. Você sabe debugar um código? Veja como debugar o código passo a passo para ver o que acontece [aqui](http://luizricardo.org/2013/11/instalando-configurando-e-usando-o-eclipse-kepler/).